# Making routerLink conditional in Angular 4+ giving in HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How do I route conditionally in Angular instead of giving it something like 'navigateByUrl="/something"', What I want to do is give condition in HTML by using [routerLink] .

Comment: need more insight on the problem.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is to give condition in the HTML document to the router link, just like we can give the conditional in typescript file like if (condition) { then this page to route } else {someother page to route}. Wish you got my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the conditional operator in the `[routerLink]` itself.

use like this:

```
[routerLink]='[cond ? "/x" : "/y"]'
```

Here `cond` is a boolean value (you can have expression also).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have expected but can we pass some sort of variable values which is declared in Typescript file and with [routerLink] we can carry it to another component and use it there somehow?

Comment: What do you mean by `carry it to another component`, how do you want to use it ? If not related to this question, I suggest posting another question with details

Comment: Okay! I'll post another question @SachinGupta. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
```

see docs by this link [angular routerLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

```
<a  [routerLink]="true?'/requests':'/req'">
```